# Is there any differences, if you create a constraint relative to parent UIView container itself, compared to safe area of parent UIView container?

Tags: ios, swift, uiview

Currently, I have a parent `UIView` container, which contains other children `UIView`

I have tried 2 different ways to create their constraints

---

### Relative to parent UIView container itself

1. trailing = Main Label.trailing + 10
2. Main Label.leading = leading + 10
3. Main.Label.centerY = centerY

[image]

---

### Relative to parent UIView container's safe area

1. Safe Area.trailing = Main Label.trailing + 10
2. Main Label.leading = Safe Area.leading + 10
3. Main.Label.centerY = Safe Area.centerY

[image]

---

They might look different in Xcode XIB UI preview, where it seems like there is top margin in safe area.

But, when I run the app, both yields the same UI appearance.

What I know, what are the differences, when we create a constraint relative to parent UIView container itself, compared to safe area of parent UIView container? Which way we should go for, most of the time?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SafeArea is just a layout guideline provided by Apple to avoid your views or any components to cover some undesired places, e.g. the status bar or the bottom bar.

Normally when I create a custom UIView, I always align the subview to their superview. (i.e. create a constraint relative to the parent UIView container itself), because I know that I want my custom UIView to appear the same no matter where they are, even they are close to the safe area.

Maybe it will be more clear with some demo:

[image]

[image]

So I created two custom view with labels centered to the superview & safearea.

[image]

they appear to be the same when you run the app, but when you move them to the safe area...

[image]

We can see the label centered to the safe area move downward, the safe area layout guides is working. (Of course we can obtain the height of the status bar, and compare the position of both labels, and we should see that the difference is exactly the status bar's height, but here I prefer to expain it visually.)

To conclude, I suggest to create constaints relative to the superview when we creating our custom view, for most of the time, to avoid any unpected behaviours.